# How I can Update the row ionto database using ADo.net Data Entity Model?

Tags: django-models, ado.net, entity

How I can Update the row into database using ADo.net Data Entity Model?

Answer (score 5):

each data row is represented by an object.

you just need to fetch the required row, update the relevant property and save the changes using the object context.

for example:

```
using(MyContext db = new MyContext())
{

var customer = db.Customers.First();


customer.Name = "New Value";

db.SaveChanges();

}
```

And your'e done.
Hope this helps.